# Get reference to the list of modifications from within Ant task

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol

I'm try to develop a cruise control step which will process database migration scripts and apply them.

I'd like to be able to get hold of a list of the modifications from the SourceControl (to see if any new database changes need to be applied).

Any ideas how I can achieve this? I know that this information is written into the log xml but  I was wondering if there is an easy mechanism to get a reference to this from with an Ant builder.

I have investigated writing a custom CC Listener or Builder plugin but neither supply this in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

We have "svn update" as one of the steps in ant builder, and later we use output redirected to the file (ant property also could be used):

```
<exec executable="svn" dir=".">
   <arg line="up"/>
   <redirector output="svnup.log" alwayslog="true" append="true"/>
</exec>
<property name="svnup.log" value="svnup.log"/>
```

this creates file named "svnup.log" in the build folder with output of "svn up" command.

Comment: I wanted to tap into and utilize the results from the modificationset part of the cruise control build. Your solution involves making an additional svn call, which would work also.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to try to write a custom plugin implementing Publisher

```
@Override
public void publish(Element cruisecontrolLog) throws CruiseControlException {     XMLLogHelper xmlHelper = new XMLLogHelper(cruisecontrolLog);
  Set<Modification> modifications = xmlHelper.getModifications();
  for (Modification modification : modifications) {
    handleModification(modification);           
  }
}
```

Or another idea is to use the timestamp flag in the sscm ant task combined with the cclastbuildtimestamp property supplied to the ant builder to produce a list of files changed since last build.